# How to navigate to dynamic view using ArrayList

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

sorry for my poor English.
I seached for hours but I couldn't find any solution for my problem.

I want to navigate my view to another from getting name of view from arrayList in DataProvider.

How can I get the clicked item's url and navigate as View.
Thanks..

```
<s:List id="listMenu" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
click="navigator.pushView(listMenu.url as View)">
<s:dataProvider>
    <s:ArrayList>
        <fx:Object name="Title1" detail="Detail1" src="@Embed('../media/graphics/credit-card.png')" url="View1" />
        <fx:Object name="Title2 Sorgulama" detail="Detail2" src="@Embed('../media/graphics/IMEI.png')" url="View2" />       
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:dataProvider>
<s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <s:IconItemRenderer labelField="name" messageField="detail" iconField="src" iconWidth="64" iconHeight="64" height="68" />               
    </fx:Component>
</s:itemRenderer>
```

Comment: Are you talking about Flex Mobile views?  Or do you must mean another component?

Comment: Hi, I'm talking about normal standart Flex Mobile views. I want to get view dynamicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go -

**assets/icons/FB.png:**

[image]

**assets/icons/GG.png:**

[image]

**views/Home.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.BitmapAsset;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.components.SplitViewNavigator;
            import spark.components.ViewNavigator;
            import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            [Embed(source="assets/icons/FB.png")] 
            private static const FB_CLASS:Class;
            [Embed(source="assets/icons/GG.png")] 
            private static const GG_CLASS:Class;

            private static const FB_ICON:BitmapAsset = new FB_CLASS() as BitmapAsset;
            private static const GG_ICON:BitmapAsset = new GG_CLASS() as BitmapAsset;

            protected function handleChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
                var item:Object = login.selectedItem;
                navigator.pushView(item.view, item.str);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    

    <s:List width="100%" height="100%" id="login" change="handleChange(event);">
        <s:dataProvider> 
            <s:ArrayCollection> 
                <fx:Object icon="{FB_ICON}" view="{FB}" label="Play at" msg="Facebook.com" /> 
                <fx:Object icon="{GG_ICON}" view="{GG}" label="Play at" msg="Google+" /> 
            </s:ArrayCollection> 
        </s:dataProvider>
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer labelField="label" iconField="icon" messageField="msg"/>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>
</s:View>
```

**App.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    firstView="views.Home">
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

The **views/FB.mxml** and **views/GG.mxml** referenced above - to be created by yourself ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, Changing url="View1" to url="{View1}" solved my issues.